# Error in unity monodevelopment

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am  getting error in building c# script in unity mono development as "An item with same key has already been added "
i am using unity 5.1 and mono development  4.1 
Any solution for tht ??[image]

Comment: Is this an error associated with a script you wrote? If so, can you include the relevant part of the script in your question? Otherwise, please give additional details on the problem.

Comment: their is  by default script tht is  void on start and void on update . 
and during build i am getting the above error

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer as i was building it without debugger. 
On top -left    their is an play button simply attach debug mode in it and thts it